# How to define xticklabel shift in axis units?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I produce the following chart:

[image]

I have defined `ymin = 4.4` in the axis options. 
In order to place the x-axis line at `y = 0` but keep the x-axis labels at the bottom of the chart, I am using: `axis x line shift= -4.4` (the same value as `ymin`) and `xticklabel shift= 3cm`.

The value of 3cm was just something I manually eyeballed.

Is there any way I can set its value based on the graph coordinates in the same way I set the x-axis line shift? I'm producing quite a lot of charts and am tired of eyeballing it!

**Even better, is there a way to ensure that the x-axis labels are always at the bottom of the chart (and at some appropriate space after the end of the y-axis)?**

---

Code for the above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

%colors
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{004B87} % blue
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{E46425} % orange

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    date, yoy, qoq
    1Q19, 4.5, 1.1
    2Q19, 4.5, 1.1
    3Q19, 4.5, 1.1
    4Q19, 4.5, 1.1
    1Q20, -3.7, -8.3
}\hchartone

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd, yshift = -0.25em, xshift = 0.6em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[
width = 8cm,
height = 8cm,
axis lines=left,
axis x line shift= -4.4,
enlarge x limits=0.1,
enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
%
% y ticks style and label
ymin = -4.4,
ylabel={Annual change, \%},
ylabel shift = 0pt,
ytick distance = 1,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize},
%
% x axis ticks and style
xticklabel shift= 3cm,
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\hchartone}{date},  
table/x expr = \coordindex,                     
x tick label style = {rotate=0},
%
% legends and labels
legend cell align={left},
legend style = {fill = none,
    draw=none,
    legend columns=1,
    at={(0.5,1.12)},
    anchor=north,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em},
},
% nodes near coords
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords style = { /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,
    /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize, yshift=0cm, xshift = 0cm,
},
]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [ybar, ybar legend, c1, fill=c1, nodes near coords, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=yoy]  {\hchartone};
\addlegendentry{Traffic};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it. Usually one would use `axis x line=middle` to place the x-axis in the middle, but to achieve what you want you "had the right feeling" to use `axis x line=left` in combination with `axis x line shift` to place it at y=0. You were also right using `xticklabel shift`, but instead of providing the `<dimension>` value *directly* you can provide it *indirectly* using `xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}}` which exactly does what you want (although I don't know *why*).

Please note that I removed a lot of unnecessary stuff of your code to keep it simply to fine the necessary stuff needed to change/add/adapt.

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \definecolor{c1}{HTML}{004B87} % blue
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        date, yoy, qoq
        1Q19, 4.5, 1.1
        2Q19, 4.5, 1.1
        3Q19, 4.5, 1.1
        4Q19, 4.5, 1.1
        1Q20, -3.7, -8.3
    }\hchartone

        \small
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        axis lines=left,
        ymin=-4.4,
        ylabel={Annual change, \%},
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\hchartone}{date},
        axis x line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}},                % <-- adjusted
        xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}},   % <-- added
        nodes near coords,
        table/x expr=\coordindex,
    ]
        \addplot table [y=yoy]  {\hchartone};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! Literally exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome.